# Meaning and fix for Elm compiler error : "Error reading build artifact"

Tags: webpack, elm

I'm using Elm 0.16 with webpack and occasionally (sometimes quiet often), I get the error message below

```
webpack: bundle is now INVALID
Error reading build artifact elm-stuff\build-artifacts\0.16.0\user\project\1.0.0\TestProject-Components-ViewManager.elmi

The file was generated by a previous build and may be outdated or corrupt
Remove the file and try again

ERROR in ./src/Main.elm
Module build failed:
 @ ./src/index.js 12:10-27
webpack: bundle is now VALID.
```

This started as the project got bigger.

For now, the project compiles when one of the following is done

- Restart the npm script that does the auto compilation
- Make any update to `index.js`. Usually I just add a space and delete it and save.

What could be the cause of this and how do I fix it?

The npm script is `"dev": "webpack-dev-server --port 3000"`

Comment: Can you provide the `.elmi` files which are causing the errors? Also, are you sure that you only have one version of Elm on your system?

Comment: Ok. Will get the `.elmi` file when it occurs. I'm sure I have only one version of Elm on my machine. Is there a way to check if I have multiple? I'm using windows 10.

Comment: It's a bit tricker on Windows. Maybe try searching for elm.exe in Windows explorer, and see what comes up? you probably only have one version, I'm guessing this is just a compiler bug.

Comment: The elmi file is [here](http://1drv.ms/1SU9Mzv). It is on onedrive. Found the exes for elm. There were no duplicates so I think there is only 1 instance